# how to add a new row for jTable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i was setting the number of rows of my Table in java using properties of the table but how can i **add new row** inside the code because i don't know the number of inputs that should be entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, i set the number of rows equal "0" in the properties of the table 
second, write this code in the for loop with your condition

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < shipmain.files.length; i++) {
            arr.add(shipmain.files[i]);
            arr.add(shipmain.fabricName[i]);
            arr.add(shipmain.color[i]);

            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
            model.addRow(arr.toArray());
            jTable1.setModel(model);
            arr.remove(shipmain.files[i]);
            arr.remove(shipmain.fabricName[i]);
            arr.remove(shipmain.color[i]);
        }
```

AddRow() function must take an object and ArrayList provided that

Comment: This assumes that the you are using a DefaultTableModel. If you're using the TableModel from the JTable, there's no need to reapply it

Answer (score 1):

> but how can i add new row inside the code

This will depend on the implementation of the `TableModel`, for example, the [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) provides two `addRow` methods.

The `TableModel` itself doesn't provide this functionality directly and is dependent on the physical implementation to provide this functionality if and when required.

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details